# How to eliminate arbitrary constants from differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have 3 equations:\begin{eqnarray}
y=Ae^{m_1x}+Be^{m_2x}\\
y^\prime=Am_1e^{m_1x}+Bm_2e^{m_2x}\\
y^{\prime\prime}=A{m_1}^2e^{m_1x}+B{m_2}^2e^{m_2x}
\end{eqnarray}
Here $m_1$ and $m_2$ are fixed constants. I need to eliminate $A$ and $B$ from the above three equations. One thing I can do is to solve for $A$ and $B$ from the last two equations and replace their values in the first equation, but that's a very tedious process. I am looking for a simpler method. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

P.S: One thing I noticed is that the answer looks like this: $y^{\prime\prime}-(m_1+m_2)y^\prime+(m_1m_2)y=0$. Notice that this is somewhat similar to the polynomial equation: $x^2-(m_1+m_2)x+(m_1m_2)=0$
Where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are solutions for $x$.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Just for fun

Comment: Your note is related to the fact on where these expressions come from. They come from solving for the roots of the associated characteristic equation of a linear constant coefficient differential equation.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Actually I was trying to find the differential equation for $$y=Ae^{-5x}+Be^{-3x}$$. But I thought of finding the most general possible case and skip all the exercises that fit into that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose $m_1 \ne m_2$:
$$(r-m_1)(r-m_2)=0$$
$$\implies r^2-(m_1+m_2)r+m_1m_2=0$$
Then you have the DE:
$$y''-(m_1+m_2)y'+m_1m_2y=0$$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what peeked into my mind, but how does $r$ relate to my differential equations?